# Displaying a background image in Kivy

Tags: python, python-3.x, canvas, kivy

I just started to learn Kivy so I am still familiar with its functionalities.
I am trying to put an image as a background to my app main page. This is what I did:

```
class Prin(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super(Prin,self).__init__(**kwargs)
        layout = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')
        with self.canvas:
            self.rect = Rectangle(source='test.png', pos=layout.center, size=(self.width, self.height))
        self.text = Label(text='Press start')
        fb = Button(text='Start!', size_hint =(0.5, 0.1), pos_hint ={'center_x':.5, 'y':.5}, padding=(10, 0), on_press=self.start)

        layout.add_widget(self.text)
        layout.add_widget(fb)
        self.add_widget(layout)
        
    def start(self,event):
        self.text.text = self.text.text+ "\nNew line"


class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
            return Prin()
    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = MainApp()
    app.run()
```

The desired behavior is an image covering the whole screen, that's why I've put `pos=self.center, size=(self.width, self.height)`

This is the output:

[image: current output]

So I have two questions:

1/ Why is the image appearing in the left bottom side ? What widget is actually there ? I am supposed to have only a BoxLayout with 2 widgets in a vertical orientation. I don't understand what is there.

2/ What should why put in size and pos to have the desired output ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend putting all graphic elements in a `.kv` file, so there are fewer imports and it looks better.

```py
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

KV = ("""
<Prin>
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        canvas.before:
            Rectangle:
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size
                source: 'test.png'
                
        Label:
            id: label
            text: 'TEXT'
                
        Button:
            text: 'Start!'
            size_hint: None, None
            size_hint: 0.5, 0.1
            pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .5}
            padding: 10, 0
            on_press: root.start()
            
""")


class Prin(BoxLayout):
    Builder.load_string(KV)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Prin, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def start(self):
        self.ids.label.text += "\nNew line"


class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Prin()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = MainApp()
    app.run()
```

If you still want to do this not in the `kv` file, then the problem is in `self.size`, by default, this value is `[100, 100]`, only after calling the class and adding it to the main window it changes.

```
from kivy.core.window import Window

class Prin(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Prin, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        with self.canvas.before:
            Rectangle(source='test.png', pos=self.pos, size=Window.size)

        print(self.size) # [100, 100]


...

class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        self.screen = Prin()
        return self.screen

    def on_start(self):
        print(self.screen.size)  # [800, 600]
```

*And don't forget about **imports** when you ask a question, the code should run without any manipulation*

Answer (score 1):

In response to your questions:

1. The image is appearing in that position because `pos=layout.center` is not a valid position and so instead sets it to a default value (`[100, 100]` I believe). To fix this, change `pos=layout.center` to `pos=layout.pos`
2. Your size is the default value also! This is getting a little technical but when you initialise your `Prin` class you are specifying the size of the `Rectangle` to be the current size of the `BoxLayout`. However, since it has not been initialised yet, the BoxLayout doesn't yet have a size! Again, Kivy handles this by giving it a default size.

*Why are my Buttons and Labels correct?*

Kivy automatically **binds** the children of a BoxLayout to the size and position of the BoxLayout. This binding ensures that when the position and size of the BoxLayout are changed, so too are the widgets within it (https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.event.html).

*Why doesn't Kivy bind the rectangle?*

This has something to do with the `canvas`. The canvas is a drawing instruction shared by a widget, and not a property of any individual widget. Hence you'll programmatically bind your rectangle to the BoxLayout. (https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.graphics.instructions.html)

*How do I achieve this binding you speak of?*

Two ways. Firstly (preferred), you can define your widgets in the KV language as this will automatically handle any binding you wish. Second, you can create an 'on_size' callback. Something like:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.graphics import Rectangle


class Prin(BoxLayout):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Prin, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        layout = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')
        with self.canvas:
            self.rect = Rectangle(source='test.png', pos=layout.pos, size=self.size)
        self.text = Label(text='Press start')
        fb = Button(text='Start!', size_hint=(0.5, 0.1), pos_hint={'center_x': .5, 'y': .5}, padding=(10, 0),
                    on_press=self.start)

        layout.add_widget(self.text)
        layout.add_widget(fb)
        self.add_widget(layout)

    def start(self, *_):
        self.text.text = self.text.text + "\nNew line"

    def resize(self, *_):
        widgets = self.children[:]
        self.canvas.clear()
        self.clear_widgets()
        with self.canvas:
            self.rect = Rectangle(source='test.png', pos=self.pos, size=self.size)
        for widget in widgets:
            self.add_widget(widget)

    on_size = resize


class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Prin()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = TestApp()
    app.run()
```

I just would like to add as a **BIG P.S.** although the above code solves your problem, it does so in probably the least efficient way imaginable. It is far better to define your widget in the kv file.